# javascript_include_tag returns nil instead google api key

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm setting up my app on production but I got stuck... 
My app is using google maps so to get this things works some sort of code was added.

Using figaro so my ENV looks like:

```
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: 'my api key'
```

then in tamplate:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY']}&callback=myMap" %>
```

In develop env everything work fine but on herokus not... 
Logs:

```html
2017-12-26T14:49:36.678130+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679197+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]   
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679260+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441] ActionView::Template::Error (nil is not a valid asset source):
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679516+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]     65:   </footer>
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679518+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]     66: </div>
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679518+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]     67: 
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679519+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]     68: <%= javascript_include_tag ENV["GoogleMap"] %>
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679520+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]     69: <%= javascript_include_tag "animate" %>
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679570+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]
```

`2017-12-26T14:49:36.678130+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679197+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]

2017-12-26T14:49:36.679260+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441] ActionView::Template::Error (nil is not a valid asset source):
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679516+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]     65:   </footer>
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679518+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]     66: </div>
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679518+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]     67: 
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679519+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]     68: <%= javascript_include_tag ENV["GoogleMap"] %>
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679520+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]     69: <%= javascript_include_tag "animate" %>
2017-12-26T14:49:36.679570+00:00 app[web.1]: [20faebf2-3d32-4a2a-a257-a3585348f441]`

Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command allows copy your configuration to heroku:

`figaro heroku:set -e production`